# GCC/G++: building without GNU unique object symbols for older Linux kernels

Tags: linux, gcc

I am currently working on updating the build system for a large pile of code, which happens to include a Linux C++ project. It would be nice if all of the developers here could run a build when hacking around with their own ideas, so I was examining if it would be possible to build this on vaguely modern Linux systems despite the target system being 2.6.18.

By 'vaguely modern' I am estimating something like GCC 4.5+, something that a distribution in the past year or two might come with. Currently I solve the libstdc++ issue by compiling that in statically, and any glibc issues are neatly worked around by remapping to old versions of the memcpy symbols (and so on) with a quick bit of wrapper code. So far so good.

The one problem I can't seem to completely figure out is that certain symbols built into the executable from the .o files are of type 'u', which is a GNU unique object, an extension to the ELF standard that 2.6.18 doesn't seem to recognise at all. This means the executable won't run because it can't find the symbols, though they are in fact present (just of type '?' on the target, from 'nm').

One can disable the use of GNU unique objects when compiling G++ but it's not exactly the most convenient solution. I can't see any way to just disable it when compiling code (distro gcc/g++ invariably has this option on), and I imagine the only way to get the target system to recognise it would be to update ld-linux and the kernel. That's almost certainly not going to happen.

Is there an option I haven't found to disable these symbol types? Or perhaps is there some neat way around this, or something that I'm missing? I am beginning to suspect it will just have to be compiled on G++ 4.1.x, which will mean an old Linux installation or building that from source.

Comment: if this is a dynamic linking symbol type, then there should be an issue with the dynamic linker, not the kernel. How does this relate to the kernel?

Comment: While I haven't tried it, I think changing the libld without changing the kernel is going to be pretty hard - if it's possible at all. So it's not directly related to the kernel, but more of the fact I'd have to recompile that kernel or just upgrade the whole OS to get the linker to recognise these other symbols, as I understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to deal with the same problem (which led me to finding this question) and after a bunch of research came to the definitive conclusion that no, you are not missing anything, there is no way around this besides compiling your own g++. See this recent question on the gcc-help mailing list:

http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-01/msg00008.html

I compared gcc sources and found that you can go as high as stock 4.4, as unique symbols were added in 4.5. However on RHEL/CentOS 6 they default to 4.4 but patched unique symbol support into it, so as usual one must beware of distribution-specific gcc versions. For me this is a huge bummer as it means that things compiled on RHEL 6 can't be run on RHEL 5, even with a copy of libstdc++ made just for gcc 4.4 + RHEL 5.

Here's the message where unique symbol support was first proposed, by the way:

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2009-07/msg01240.html

If you search around you'll find that people have complained about it on other lists for various reasons, but I guess it's here to stay.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll just have to complain louder about upgrading the Linux kernel :)